# Emacs automatic encoding conversion

Tags: emacs, encoding

When I open a buffer in Emacs containing a German Umlaut (the word "PrÃ¤sentation" occurs in a string), Emacs automatically converts it to a different encoding as soon as I save the file.

How can I tell Emacs to leave the encoding alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want [`find-file-literally`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html).

Comment: Ah, that looks pretty much like it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

`M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system` is what you are looking for.

You might also have a look at http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_221.html.

Comment: Thx for the answer. This command sets the encoding explicitly, but I want to leave the encoding as it is, I think that's a different problem. And I want to avoid having to execute a command whenever I encounter a buffer containing "special" characters. Could the real problem be that Emacs initially guesses the file's encoding incorrectly? Maybe setting `file-coding-system-alist` properly could help ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its a bug in stackoverflow, or you really mean you see an A~ and universal currency symbol in Emacs.  If the problem is Emacs displaying the wrong characters, then the following might help:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```